# How to make two different arrays into one 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

There are two different String arrays.

```
String a[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
String b[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
```

And I want to make these two arrays into a 4*2 matrix.

```
String answer[][] = {{"a", "1"}, {"b", "2"}, {"c", "3"}, {"d", "4"}};
```

How can I make this matrix?

```
String[][] result = {a,b};
```

After making this result, is there any other way to rotate the rows and columns of the result?

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far?

Comment: "I want to make these two arrays into a 4*2 matrix." You've got the syntax, right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
public static String[][] convert(String[] a, String[] b) {
    String[][] res = new String[a.length][];

    for(int row = 0; row < a.length; row++)
        res[row] = new String[] { a[row], b[row] };

    return res;
}
```